# Send String from Edittext on 1st Activity to the Edittext on the 2nd Activity

Tags: java, android, database, android-intent

I have some string that i write into the Edittext on my first activity and im trying to send it to the Edittext on the other activity by pressing Button, but my code does not work, nothing happen and i dont know what else can i do here maybe somebody could help me out

My onClick method at 1st activity:

```
public void calendarOR(View v, AdapterView<?> parent, int position, long id) {
        String data = cala.getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), calendar.class);
        intent.putExtra("id",data);
        startActivity(intent);
```

My second activity code:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    userId = extras.getLong("id");
}
if (userId > 0) {
    userCursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + dbelper.TABLE + " where " + dbelper.COLUMN_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(userId)});
    userCursor.moveToFirst();
    date.setText(userCursor.getString(1));
    userCursor.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting a `String` data type and trying to get a `long`. Change the second activity to get the "id" as a string.

```
userId = extras.getString("id");
```

then

```
if (userId != null) {
    userCursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + dbelper.TABLE + " where " + dbelper.COLUMN_ID + "=?", new String[]{userId});
    userCursor.moveToFirst();
    date.setText(userCursor.getString(1));
    userCursor.close();
}
```

You may also want to print log messages if userId is null or the data is not in the database to help with debugging.

Unrelated, but you may want to change your intent to not use the application context, like this, to launch the `calendar` activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, calendar.class);
```

Comment: thank you very much, now at least it allows me to get further but now i get an Error "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kp_orginizer/com.example.kp_orginizer.calendar}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0" in "date.setText(userCursor.getString(1));" could you please tell me whats wrong?

Comment: That sounds like your SQL query is returning an empty result. I'd recommend marking this as accepted and asking a new question if you can't figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

do this in second activity code:

`String data =getIntent().getStringExtra("id");`

Comment: For some reason it doesnt allow "getStringExtra" and gives an Error so i can only use "getString"